# Proguard issue “Warning:Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class”

Tags: android

I am getting this error log while building APK. Please help me with this. Thanks in advance.

My Gradle file

```
     minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.2"
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    dexOptions {
        javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile files('libs/glide-3.7.0.jar')
    compile files('libs/android-async-http-1.4.4.jar')
    compile('com.github.ozodrukh:CircularReveal:2.0.1@aar') {
        transitive = true;
    }

    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.7'
    compile 'com.mcxiaoke.volley:library-aar:1.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:25.3.1'
    compile 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.1.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:10.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
    compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:10.0.1'
    compile 'com.googlecode.ez-vcard:ez-vcard:0.10.2'
    compile 'com.applozic.communication.uiwidget:audiovideo:1.2'
    compile 'com.itextpdf:itextg:5.5.9'
    compile 'lib.kashif:folderpicker:2.2'
    compile 'com.yovenny.VideoCompress:videocompress:1.0.0'
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

My Proguard File is

```
-keep class com.itextpdf.** { *; }
-dontwarn com.itextpdf.**
-dontwarn com.squareup.picasso.**
-keep class org.apache.http.** { *; }
-dontwarn org.apache.http.**
-keep class android.net.http.** { *; }
-dontwarn android.net.http.**
-keepattributes InnerClasses
-optimizations optimization_filter
```

and finally the error log

> Information:Gradle tasks [:app:assembleDebug]
>       Error:warning: Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class
>       Error:(freemarker.cache.FileTemplateLoader$1) that doesn't come with an
>       Error:associated EnclosingMethod attribute. This class was probably produced by a
>       Error:compiler that did not target the modern .class file format. The recommended
>       Error:solution is to recompile the class from source, using an up-to-date compiler
>       Error:and without specifying any "-target" type options. The consequence of ignoring
>       Error:this warning is that reflective operations on this class will incorrectly
>       Error:indicate that it is *not* an inner class.
>       Error:warning: Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class
>       Error:(freemarker.cache.FileTemplateLoader$2) that doesn't come with an
>       Error:associated EnclosingMethod attribute. This class was probably produced by a
>       Error:compiler that did not target the modern .class file format. The recommended
>       Error:solution is to recompile the class from source, using an up-to-date compiler
>       Error:and without specifying any "-target" type options. The consequence of ignoring
>       Error:this warning is that reflective operations on this class will incorrectly
>       Error:indicate that it is *not* an inner class.
>       Error:warning: Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class
>       Error:(freemarker.cache.FileTemplateLoader$4) that doesn't come with an
>       Error:associated EnclosingMethod attribute. This class was probably produced by a
>       Error:compiler that did not target the modern .class file format. The recommended
>       Error:solution is to recompile the class from source, using an up-to-date compiler
>       Error:and without specifying any "-target" type options. The consequence of ignoring
>       Error:this warning is that reflective operations on this class will incorrectly
>       Error:indicate that it is *not* an inner class.
>       Error:warning: Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class
>       Error:(freemarker.cache.FileTemplateLoader$3) that doesn't come with an
>       Error:associated EnclosingMethod attribute. This class was probably produced by a
>       Error:compiler that did not target the modern .class file format. The recommended
>       Error:solution is to recompile the class from source, using an up-to-date compiler
>       Error:and without specifying any "-target" type options. The consequence of ignoring
>       Error:this warning is that reflective operations on this class will incorrectly
>       Error:indicate that it is *not* an inner class.
>       Error:warning: Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class
>       Error:(freemarker.cache.TemplateCache$1) that doesn't come with an
>       Error:associated EnclosingMethod attribute. This class was probably produced by a
>       Error:compiler that did not target the modern .class file format. The recommended
>       Error:solution is to recompile the class from source, using an up-to-date compiler
>       Error:and without specifying any "-target" type options. The consequence of ignoring
>       Error:this warning is that reflective operations on this class will incorrectly
>       Error:indicate that it is *not* an inner class.
>       Error:warning: Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class
>       Error:(freemarker.cache.TemplateLookupResult$1) that doesn't come with an
>       Error:associated EnclosingMethod attribute. This class was probably produced by a
>       Error:compiler that did not target the modern .class file format. The recommended
>       Error:solution is to recompile the class from source, using an up-to-date compiler
>       Error:and without specifying any "-target" type options. The consequence of ignoring
>       Error:this warning is that reflective operations on this class will incorrectly
>       Error:indicate that it is *not* an inner class.
>       Error:warning: Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class
>       Error:(freemarker.cache.TemplateLookupStrategy$1) that doesn't come with an
>       Error:associated EnclosingMethod attribute. This class was probably produced by a
>       Error:compiler that did not target the modern .class file format. The recommended
>       Error:solution is to recompile the class from source, using an up-to-date compiler
>       Error:and without specifying any "-target" type options. The consequence of ignoring
>       Error:this warning is that reflective operations on this class will incorrectly
>       Error:indicate that it is *not* an inner class.
>       Error:warning: Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class
>       Error:(freemarker.cache.TemplateNameFormat$1) that doesn't come with an
>       Error:associated EnclosingMethod attribute. This class was probably produced by a
>       Error:compiler that did not target the modern .class file format. The recommended
>       Error:solution is to recompile the class from source, using an up-to-date compiler
>       Error:and without specifying any "-target" type options. The consequence of ignoring
>       Error:this warning is that reflective operations on this class will incorrectly
>       Error:indicate that it is *not* an inner class.
>       Error:warning: Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class
>       Error:(freemarker.core.BlockAssignment$CaptureOutput$1) that doesn't come with an
>       Error:associated EnclosingMethod attribute. This class was probably produced by a
>       Error:compiler that did not target the modern .class file format. The recommended
>       Error:solution is to recompile the class from source, using an up-to-date compiler
>       Error:and without specifying any "-target" type options. The consequence of ignoring
>       Error:this warning is that reflective operations on this class will incorrectly
>       Error:indicate that it is *not* an inner class.
>       Error:warning: Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous

Answer (score 0):

add this to the proguard

```
  -dontwarn freemarker.**
```

or the another solution is- this is because of some dependencies so add this in the build.gradle (app)

```
    dependencies {
        compile ('com.mylib.lib') {
            exclude group: 'org.freemarker'
        }
    }
```